# Does the height of Android 4.1 notification's expanded view need to be in multiples of 1U/64dp (normal view)?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to design a custom 'BigView' or 'expanded view' as per [Android 4.1 design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html). As I understand the small/normal notification has a height of 64dp, keeping that in mind, I was wondering if there are any guidelines which state that the expanded view needs to be in multiples of 64dp/1U or can any height be used for the notifications (upto a maximum of 4U)?

[image]

I'm asking this question because it makes sense to have expanded notifications that are 2,3 or 4x the size of the basic notification and not just some random value (which might vary from app to app)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope. Can be any size you want between 64 and 256dp. BigTextStyle, for example, wraps its content TextView, so its height varies based on the amount of text you stuff in there.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), the maximum height of the Big notification content is 256dp.

> The height available for a custom notification layout depends on the notification view. Normal view layouts are limited to 64 dp, and expanded view layouts are limited to 256 dp.

Comment: I did mention that the maximum height is 4U (256dp), my question was more around, if the height should be multiples of 1U (64dp)

Comment: what is the width